# Longest Increasing Subsequence, Dynamic Programing

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have the following problem:

> Find the longest increasing subsequence of a given sequence / array.
>
> In other words, find a subsequence of array in which the subsequence’s
>   elements are in strictly increasing order, and in which the
>   subsequence is as long as possible.  This subsequence is not
>   necessarily contiguous, or unique. In this case, we only care about
>   the length of the longest increasing subsequence.
>
> Example :
>
> Input : [0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15] Output
>   : 6 The sequence : [0, 2, 6, 9, 13, 15] or [0, 4, 6, 9, 11, 15] or [0,
>   4, 6, 9, 13, 15]

This is a DP problem and I do have some issue at the memorization step.
Here is my code:

```
public int lis(final List<Integer> a) {
    return maxIncreasing(0, Integer.MIN_VALUE, a);
}
HashMap<Integer, Integer> memo = new HashMap<>();
private int maxIncreasing(int index, int lastElt, final List<Integer> a) {
    if(memo.containsKey(index)) return memo.get(index);
    // end?
    if(index >= a.size()) return 0;
    int weTake = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    // can we take it?
    if(a.get(index) > lastElt) {
        // take it or don't
        weTake = maxIncreasing(index + 1, a.get(index), a) + 1;
    }
    int weDoNot = maxIncreasing(index + 1, lastElt, a);
    int max = Math.max(weTake, weDoNot);
    memo.put(index, max);
    return max;
}
```

Without the memo HashMap in place I have the correct result, I am not sure why this is giving me the wrong result once in place.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are not taking care of the `lastElt`. Basically, you can have more than one solution for a given `index` depending on what was the `lastElt` value. Therefore, you would have to have a `Key` for your `memo` that contains both `index` and `lastElt`.

You could do something like this:

```
    class Key {
        final int index;
        final int lastEl;

        Key(int index, int lastEl) {
            this.index = index;
            this.lastEl = lastEl;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

            Key key = (Key) o;

            if (index != key.index) return false;
            return lastEl == key.lastEl;

        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int result = index;
            result = 31 * result + lastEl;
            return result;
        }
    }

    public int lis(final List<Integer> a) {
        return maxIncreasing(0, Integer.MIN_VALUE, a);
    }
    HashMap<Key, Integer> memo = new HashMap<>();
    private int maxIncreasing(int index, int lastElt, final List<Integer> a) {
        Key key = new Key(index ,lastElt);
        if(memo.containsKey(key)) return memo.get(key);
        // end?
        if(index >= a.size()) return 0;
        int weTake = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        // can we take it?
        if(a.get(index) > lastElt) {
            // take it or don't
            weTake = maxIncreasing(index + 1, a.get(index), a) + 1;
        }
        int weDoNot = maxIncreasing(index + 1, lastElt, a);
        int max = Math.max(weTake, weDoNot);
        memo.put(key, max);
        return max;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this solution is valid, however still giving me some issue performance wise, probably the recursion is causing memory overhead.

Comment: You should try implementing it using dynamic programming. Instead of using a recursion and memoization, you should use an array to calculate all the results as shown here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-3-longest-increasing-subsequence/